# How the property isCompleted of IAsyncResult is updated?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asynchronous

When I call a method asynchronously (using the pattern BeginXxx/EndXxx), I get an `IAsyncResult` result after calling the BeginXxx. How does the property "isCompleted" (in the returning result variable) get updated if neither the method BeginXxxx or EndXxx have any reference to the result variable?

ex:

```
// Create the delegate.
AsyncMethodCaller caller = new AsyncMethodCaller(ad.TestMethod);

// Initiate the asychronous call.
IAsyncResult result = caller.BeginInvoke(3000, out threadId, null, null);

// Poll while simulating work.
while(result.IsCompleted == false) {
    Thread.Sleep(250);
    Console.Write(".");
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`BeginInvoke` is returning you the `IAsyncResult` so it will have a reference to it. This will be internally created and sent back to you.

For example, `BeginRead` in FileStream creates `FileStreamAsyncResult` and then returns it:

```
private unsafe FileStreamAsyncResult BeginReadCore(byte[] bytes, int offset, int numBytes, AsyncCallback userCallback, object stateObject, int numBufferedBytesRead)
{
    NativeOverlapped* overlappedPtr;
    FileStreamAsyncResult ar = new FileStreamAsyncResult {
        _handle = this._handle,
        _userCallback = userCallback,
        _userStateObject = stateObject,
        _isWrite = false,
        _numBufferedBytes = numBufferedBytesRead
    };
    ManualResetEvent event2 = new ManualResetEvent(false);
    ar._waitHandle = event2;

    .....

    if (hr == 0x6d)
    {
        overlappedPtr->InternalLow = IntPtr.Zero;
        ar.CallUserCallback();
        return ar;
    }
```

Comment: ok. It makes sense. So this reference is passed through the XxxxEnd that changes the isCompleted property to false. Thanks...